# Is there a way to combine these redirects?

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess

I have two redirects (one for http and one for https):

```
# Option 1a: rewrite www.example.com → example.com

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# Option 1b: rewrite https://www.example.com → https://example.com

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Is it possible to combine them, and remove the subdomain for both http and https with one ruleset (without having to specify the exact domain, like the current rules)?

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372594/preserve-http-https-protocol-in-htaccess-redirects

Comment: @tzafar Yes, I've seen that, but that requires the domain to be specified, which is what I'm trying to avoid. I've tried to adapt it to my use-case, but am stuck with trying to make the domain a variable..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can combine both rules into one without hardcoding hostname:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}#%{HTTPS}s ^www\.([^#]+)#(?:off|on(s)) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http%2://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I changed the redirect to a 301 and removed the `NE` like in the original question. Other than that, perfect.

Comment: Yes 302 is for testing only. Once verified you can make it 301.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS}:s on:(s)
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http%1://%2%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Would `%1` not contain the domain name in cases where the request isn't https? Surely if there's no match the group won't get populated?