# Redirect all image urls to my CDN - Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I'm using a CDN for serving my images on my Wordpress..

The URL structure goes as such:

> //mydomain.com/assets/uploads/[year]/[month]/[day]/[imagename].png or whatever

For my CDN the images are served as:

> //cdn.cdnnetwork.com/mydomain.com/assets/uploads/[year]/[month]/[day]/[imagename].png or whatever

Now the problem is that whenever the image gets accessed directly either with typing in the exact url or a search engine redirecting it they all go to:

> //mydomain.com/assets/uploads/[year]/[month]/[day]/[imagename].png or whatever

I want to use .htaccess rule or any other way to redirect all

> //mydomain.com/assets/uploads/[year]/[month]/[day]/[imagename].png or whatever

links to:

> //cdn.cdnnetwork.com/mydomain.com/assets/uploads/[year]/[month]/[day]/[imagename].png or whatever

So I can save bandwidth... Is it possible? The images embedded in a actual webpage using the img tag are fine it's just direct access to the images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be doable. Your .htaccess file (in www root) would look something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [env=proto:https]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [env=proto:http]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com/assets$
RewriteRule ([^.]+\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png))$ %{ENV:proto}://cdn.cdnnetwork.com/mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

See this answer for more information on how to preserve the protocol (http/https): [Preserve HTTP/HTTPS protocol in .htaccess redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372594/preserve-http-https-protocol-in-htaccess-redirects)

Comment: Can this code be edited to only apply to images..? I have other files on the directory which are not served by a CDN..

Comment: See updated answer. This should match any file that ends in jpg, jpeg, gif, bmp, or png.